# Is it sensible to fit a KNN model to ordinal variables?

Tags: ordinal-data, k-nearest-neighbour

I need to fit a KNN model to my dataset, which consists mostly of ordinal variables. One such variable is `Education`, with levels 0, 1, 2 and 3, ordered low to high.
(I'm using R with the `knn()` function from the `class` package, whose documentation doesn't mention this specific case.)
Is it sensible to fit a KNN model to such dataset?

Comment: It might be OK, I think. Not sure though, no personal experience with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think it is sensible as long as you can come up with a sensible notion of distance between objects described in terms of categorical variables.